# Convert Special Characters to HTML - ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I need to convert a lot of special characters to their html format and I am trying to do this with a function that is using `ReplaceList` but something is wrong with the function or the values I am passing to it.

This is the function

```
<cffunction name="HtmlUnEditFormat" access="public" returntype="string" output="no" displayname="HtmlUnEditFormat" hint="Undo escaped characters">
    <cfargument name="str" type="string" required="Yes" />
    <cfscript>
        var lEntities = "&##xE7;,&##xF4;,&##xE2;,&Icirc;,&Ccedil;,&Egrave;,&Oacute;,&Ecirc;,&OElig,&Acirc;,&laquo;,&raquo;,&Agrave;,&Eacute;,&le;,&yacute;,&chi;,&sum;,&prime;,&yuml;,&sim;,&beta;,&lceil;,&ntilde;,&szlig;,&bdquo;,&acute;,&middot;,&ndash;,&sigmaf;,&reg;,&dagger;,&oplus;,&otilde;,&eta;,&rceil;,&oacute;,&shy;,&gt;,&phi;,&ang;,&rlm;,&alpha;,&cap;,&darr;,&upsilon;,&image;,&sup3;,&rho;,&eacute;,&sup1;,&lt;,&cent;,&cedil;,&pi;,&sup;,&divide;,&fnof;,&iquest;,&ecirc;,&ensp;,&empty;,&forall;,&emsp;,&gamma;,&iexcl;,&oslash;,&not;,&agrave;,&eth;,&alefsym;,&ordm;,&psi;,&otimes;,&delta;,&ouml;,&deg;,&cong;,&ordf;,&lsaquo;,&clubs;,&acirc;,&ograve;,&iuml;,&diams;,&aelig;,&and;,&loz;,&egrave;,&frac34;,&amp;,&nsub;,&nu;,&ldquo;,&isin;,&ccedil;,&circ;,&copy;,&aacute;,&sect;,&mdash;,&euml;,&kappa;,&notin;,&lfloor;,&ge;,&igrave;,&harr;,&lowast;,&ocirc;,&infin;,&brvbar;,&int;,&macr;,&frac12;,&curren;,&asymp;,&lambda;,&frasl;,&lsquo;,&hellip;,&oelig;,&pound;,&hearts;,&minus;,&atilde;,&epsilon;,&nabla;,&exist;,&auml;,&mu;,&frac14;,&nbsp;,&equiv;,&bull;,&larr;,&laquo;,&oline;,&or;,&euro;,&micro;,&ne;,&cup;,&aring;,&iota;,&iacute;,&perp;,&para;,&rarr;,&raquo;,&ucirc;,&omicron;,&sbquo;,&thetasym;,&ni;,&part;,&rdquo;,&weierp;,&permil;,&sup2;,&sigma;,&sdot;,&scaron;,&yen;,&xi;,&plusmn;,&real;,&thorn;,&rang;,&ugrave;,&radic;,&zwj;,&there4;,&uarr;,&times;,&thinsp;,&theta;,&rfloor;,&sub;,&supe;,&uuml;,&rsquo;,&zeta;,&trade;,&icirc;,&piv;,&zwnj;,&lang;,&tilde;,&uacute;,&uml;,&prop;,&upsih;,&omega;,&crarr;,&tau;,&sube;,&rsaquo;,&prod;,&quot;,&lrm;,&spades;";
        var lEntitiesChars = "ç,ô,â,Î,Ç,È,Ó,Ê,Œ,Â,«,»,À,É,?,ý,?,?,?,Ÿ,?,?,?,ñ,ß,„,´,·,–,?,®,‡,?,õ,?,?,ó,­,>,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,³,?,é,¹,<,¢,¸,?,?,÷,ƒ,¿,ê,?,?,?,?,?,¡,ø,¬,à,ð,?,º,?,?,?,ö,°,?,ª,‹,?,â,ò,ï,?,æ,?,?,è,¾,&,?,?,“,?,ç,ˆ,©,á,§,—,ë,?,?,?,?,ì,?,?,ô,?,¦,?,¯,½,¤,?,?,?,‘,…,œ,£,?,?,ã,?,?,?,ä,?,¼, ,?,•,?,«,?,?,€,µ,?,?,å,?,í,?,¶,?,»,û,?,‚,?,?,?,”,?,‰,²,?,?,š,¥,?,±,?,þ,?,ù,?,?,?,?,×,?,?,?,?,?,ü,’,?,™,î,?,?,?,˜,ú,¨,?,?,?,?,?,?,›,?,"",?,?";
    </cfscript>
    <cfreturn ReplaceList(arguments.str, lEntities, lEntitiesChars) />
</cffunction>
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop query="local.q" startrow="2">
       #HtmlUnEditFormat(consultServiceType)# <br />
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

These are the strings I am passing to it:

```
Security?
Security Guard®
Alarm System©
Private Investigator;
```

I am not getting any errors back (I had a cftry in the function before) and the strings come back the same

EDIT:

I've tried using #FindNoCase('©',consultServiceType)# and is returning 0 so I guess something is wrong with the string I am passing in?

Comment: Maybe it's a display issue.  Try outputting the results in a textarea or inside pre tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using CF11, did you try [EncodeForHTML()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForHTML) ?

Comment: No I will now though`1

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is the better approach (don't reinvent the wheel), but your function isn't working because you have `lEntities` and `lEntitiesChars` mixed up.

```
<cffunction name="HtmlUnEditFormat" access="public" returntype="string" output="no" displayname="HtmlUnEditFormat" hint="Undo escaped characters">
    <cfargument name="str" type="string" required="Yes" />
    <cfscript>
        var lEntities = "&##xE7;,&##xF4;,&##xE2;,&Icirc;,&Ccedil;,&Egrave;,&Oacute;,&Ecirc;,&OElig,&Acirc;,&laquo;,&raquo;,&Agrave;,&Eacute;,&le;,&yacute;,&chi;,&sum;,&prime;,&yuml;,&sim;,&beta;,&lceil;,&ntilde;,&szlig;,&bdquo;,&acute;,&middot;,&ndash;,&sigmaf;,&reg;,&dagger;,&oplus;,&otilde;,&eta;,&rceil;,&oacute;,&shy;,&gt;,&phi;,&ang;,&rlm;,&alpha;,&cap;,&darr;,&upsilon;,&image;,&sup3;,&rho;,&eacute;,&sup1;,&lt;,&cent;,&cedil;,&pi;,&sup;,&divide;,&fnof;,&iquest;,&ecirc;,&ensp;,&empty;,&forall;,&emsp;,&gamma;,&iexcl;,&oslash;,&not;,&agrave;,&eth;,&alefsym;,&ordm;,&psi;,&otimes;,&delta;,&ouml;,&deg;,&cong;,&ordf;,&lsaquo;,&clubs;,&acirc;,&ograve;,&iuml;,&diams;,&aelig;,&and;,&loz;,&egrave;,&frac34;,&amp;,&nsub;,&nu;,&ldquo;,&isin;,&ccedil;,&circ;,&copy;,&aacute;,&sect;,&mdash;,&euml;,&kappa;,&notin;,&lfloor;,&ge;,&igrave;,&harr;,&lowast;,&ocirc;,&infin;,&brvbar;,&int;,&macr;,&frac12;,&curren;,&asymp;,&lambda;,&frasl;,&lsquo;,&hellip;,&oelig;,&pound;,&hearts;,&minus;,&atilde;,&epsilon;,&nabla;,&exist;,&auml;,&mu;,&frac14;,&nbsp;,&equiv;,&bull;,&larr;,&laquo;,&oline;,&or;,&euro;,&micro;,&ne;,&cup;,&aring;,&iota;,&iacute;,&perp;,&para;,&rarr;,&raquo;,&ucirc;,&omicron;,&sbquo;,&thetasym;,&ni;,&part;,&rdquo;,&weierp;,&permil;,&sup2;,&sigma;,&sdot;,&scaron;,&yen;,&xi;,&plusmn;,&real;,&thorn;,&rang;,&ugrave;,&radic;,&zwj;,&there4;,&uarr;,&times;,&thinsp;,&theta;,&rfloor;,&sub;,&supe;,&uuml;,&rsquo;,&zeta;,&trade;,&icirc;,&piv;,&zwnj;,&lang;,&tilde;,&uacute;,&uml;,&prop;,&upsih;,&omega;,&crarr;,&tau;,&sube;,&rsaquo;,&prod;,&quot;,&lrm;,&spades;";
        var lEntitiesChars = "ç,ô,â,Î,Ç,È,Ó,Ê,Œ,Â,«,»,À,É,?,ý,?,?,?,Ÿ,?,?,?,ñ,ß,„,´,·,–,?,®,‡,?,õ,?,?,ó,­,>,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,³,?,é,¹,<,¢,¸,?,?,÷,ƒ,¿,ê,?,?,?,?,?,¡,ø,¬,à,ð,?,º,?,?,?,ö,°,?,ª,‹,?,â,ò,ï,?,æ,?,?,è,¾,&,?,?,“,?,ç,ˆ,©,á,§,—,ë,?,?,?,?,ì,?,?,ô,?,¦,?,¯,½,¤,?,?,?,‘,…,œ,£,?,?,ã,?,?,?,ä,?,¼, ,?,•,?,«,?,?,€,µ,?,?,å,?,í,?,¶,?,»,û,?,‚,?,?,?,”,?,‰,²,?,?,š,¥,?,±,?,þ,?,ù,?,?,?,?,×,?,?,?,?,?,ü,’,?,™,î,?,?,?,˜,ú,¨,?,?,?,?,?,?,›,?,"",?,?";
    </cfscript>
    <cfreturn ReplaceList(arguments.str, lEntitiesChars, lEntities) />
</cffunction>
<cfoutput>#htmluneditformat("Company?")#</cfoutput>
```

Further, `#ReplaceList()#` in both ACF and Railo/Lucee *recurse* through the list, which means the *order of the lists* matter. With the fix I suggest, `?` becomes `&amp;le;`. A fix to this would be to move `&` and the code for it to the beginning of each list.

Consider this simple piece of code

```
<cfoutput>#replacelist("abc","a,b","b,c")#</cfoutput>
```

You would probably expect the output to be "bcc", but that's not how ReplaceList works, it works something more like this

```
  <cfset sx = "abc">  
  <cfset listf = "a,b">
  <cfset listr = "b,c">
  <cfloop from="1" to="#listlen(listf)#" index="i">
    <cfset sx = replace(sx,listgetat(listf,i),listgetat(listr,i),"ALL")>
    <!--- iteration one replaces a with b to make bbc --->
    <!--- iteration two replaces b with c to make ccc --->
  </cfloop>
```

I'm not suggesting that someone use this code when CF has the built in functionality, I'm merely explaining why it doesn't work and a pitfall of `ReplaceList().`

Comment: thanks for the post. I will have this in mind for the future!